# LoadError: UndefVarError in julia for loop

Tags: julia

I am defining a variable phi_old at the start of my function, and assigning it a value of phi_start.
I then have an iterative loop that:

- uses phi_old
- solves a PDE to get a solution T
- uses the solution T to calculate phi_new
- checks the difference between phi_new and phi_old, if it is larger than error the iterative loop begins again, with phi_old using the values of phi_new.
- if the difference is less than the error, the iteration stops.

But I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Assignment to `T` in soft scope is ambiguous because a global variable by the same name exists:
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: phi_old not defined
```

Here is an example of my code's structure:

```
phi_old = createCellVariable(m,phi_start)

for i=1:i_end
 phi_new = myfunction(T)
 error = sum(phi_new.value[2,1:end]-phi_old.value[2,1:end])
 if error > 1E-03
  phi_old = phi_new
 else
  i=i+1
  break
 end
end
```

Are there any techniques I could use to better initialize/assign my arrays and fix this error? The arrays are quite large, so I would like to preallocate if possible, and only copy arrays if necessary.

Comment: It looks like your code is not the same as your example, since this example shouldn't produce error like the one you shown. Can you provide actual minimal example, which can be run on someone else computer without extra efforts and generate error?

Comment: `for` loops introduce a new scope, and the mere presence of `phi_old` as an l-value inside the loop causes it to be declared as a new variable shadowing the global `phi_old`, but since you haven't given this variable a value before the `error = ...` line, it's an error. To fix this, use `global phi_old` at the top of the loop.